# VB.NET nested for loops

Tags: vb.net

I am having two datasets,I have to check if plant code is 1st dataset and 2nd dataset then i have to set some value for a variable.If plant code is in 1st dataset and not in second dataset then have to set some value.I have try this with following code,but i m not getting output as i want

```
If Not dsCheckForBOM Is Nothing AndAlso dsCheckForBOM.Tables.Count > 0 Then

    If dsCheckForBOM.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

        For count1 As Int32 = 0 To dsCheckForBOM.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            For count2 As Int32 = 0 To dsTmpMat.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                If dsTmpMat.Tables(0).Rows(count2)("PLANT_CODE").ToString() = dsCheckForBOM.Tables(0).Rows(count1)("PLANT_CODE").ToString() Then
                    dsTmpMat.Tables(0).Rows(count2)("BOM_IND") = 1
                    dsTmpMat.Tables(0).Rows(count2)("BOM_DESC") = "BOM CREATED"
                    If count2 < dsTmpMat.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 AndAlso count1 < dsCheckForBOM.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 Then
                        count2 = count2 + 1
                        count1 = count1 + 1

                    End If
                Else
                    dsTmpMat.Tables(0).Rows(count2)("BOM_IND") = 0
                    dsTmpMat.Tables(0).Rows(count2)("BOM_DESC") = "BOM NOT CREATED"
                    If count2 < dsTmpMat.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 Then
                        count2 = count2 + 1
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Else
        For i As Int32 = 0 To dsTmpMat.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            dsTmpMat.Tables(0).Rows(i)("BOM_IND") = 0
            dsTmpMat.Tables(0).Rows(i)("BOM_DESC") = "BOM NOT CREATED"
        Next

    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this, but I think you need to use a different approach.

First, there is no need to have two loop nested. Use the [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to find the rows in the temporary table.

Second, if you don't find the row in the temporary table then I think you need to create it, not to set the last row of the temporary table to zero

```
If Not dsCheckForBOM Is Nothing AndAlso dsCheckForBOM.Tables.Count > 0 Then

    ' To remove the clutter, assign the two tables 
    ' to two local variables and work with them
    Dim tempTable = dsTmpMat.Tables(0)
    Dim checkTable = dsCheckForBOM.Tables(0)
    If checkTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then

        ' Loop on the primary table
        For count1 As Int32 = 0 To checkTable.Rows.Count - 1

            ' Get the key to search for in the temporary table
            Dim plantCode = checkTable.Rows(count1)("PLANT_CODE").ToString()

            ' Use Select to return an array of rows that match the condition.
            ' I suppose that PLANT_CODE is a primary key value here, so just one
            ' row should be returned
            Dim foundRows = tempTable.Select("PLANT_CODE = '" plantCode + "'") 
            if foundRows.Count > 0
               foundRows(0)("BOM_IND") = 1
               foundRows(0)("BOM_DESC") = "BOM CREATED"
            Else
               ' No row found, so create a new row and add it to the temporary table
               Dim newRow = tempTable.NewRow()
               newRow("BOM_IND") = 0
               newRow("BOM_DESC") = "BOM NOT CREATED"
               tempTable.Rows.Add(newRow)
            End If
        Next
    Else
        For i As Int32 = 0 To dsTmpMat.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            dsTmpMat.Tables(0).Rows(i)("BOM_IND") = 0
            dsTmpMat.Tables(0).Rows(i)("BOM_DESC") = "BOM NOT CREATED"
        Next
    End If
End If
```